# Angular 2.0 and TypeScript - Populate <select> options from multi-dimensional array objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, angular, angular2-forms

I would like to populate the `<select name="selectmodel"> <option>` from a nested array of objects based on the selection of the `<select name="selectmake"> <option>` element.

Here is the multi-dimensional array:

```
muscleCars = [
    {
      id: 1, name: "Chevrolet", models: [
        { model: "Camaro" },
        { model: "Corvette" }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2, name: "Dodge", models: [
        { model: "Charger" },
        { model: "Challenger" },
        { model: "Viper" }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 3, name: "Ford", models: [
        { model: "GT" },
        { model: "Mustang" }
      ]
    }
];
```

This is the HTML

```
//select for Make:
<select name="selectmake" [(ngModel)]="makeListFilter">
    <option *ngFor="let muscleCar of muscleCars" [ngValue]="muscleCar.name">{{muscleCar.name}}</option>
</select>

//select for Model:
<select name="selectmodel" [(ngModel)]="modelListFilter">
    <option *ngFor="let muscleCar of muscleCars" [ngValue]="muscleCar.models">{{muscleCar.models}}</option>
</select>
```

So, basically when you select Chevrolet for example, I would like to have the second element populated with `Camaro` and `Corvette`.

Currently, the second `select` element is populated with an array `[object Object]` for each make, but can't figure out how to dig this deeper.

[image]

Here is a plunk:
https://embed.plnkr.co/0eEIJg5uzL6KsI70wWsC/

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: read this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37376286/angular2-cascading-select

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how your HTML should look like:

```
<select name="selectmake" [(ngModel)]="makeListFilter">
    <option *ngFor="let muscleCar of muscleCars" [ngValue]="muscleCar">{{muscleCar.name}}</option>
</select>

<select name="selectmodel" [(ngModel)]="modelListFilter">
    <option *ngFor="let carModel of makeListFilter?.models" [ngValue]="carModel.model">{{carModel.model}}</option>
</select>
```

So, what's happening here is that selected value of `selectmake` dropdown is binded to `makeListFilter` and second dropdown `selectmodel` is populated based on selected value of first dropdown. You will notice I binded the whole `Object` that is selected in first dropdown using `ngValue` directive so it can be used to populate second dropdown. Another interesting thing you'll notice is `Elvis` operator (`?`) I used in second dropdown - it is used to tell second dropdown to populate itself only after value is selected in first dropdown, this is necessary to avoid getting error for iterating through an `undefined` value. If you don't want to use `Elvis` operator, you can use `*ngIf` directive to prevent getting mentioned error, but that means that second dropdown will appear only after you select something in the first dropdown:

```
<select *ngIf="makeListFilter" name="selectmodel" [(ngModel)]="modelListFilter">
    <option *ngFor="let carModel of makeListFilter.models" [ngValue]="carModel.model">{{carModel.model}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Modified @mrTodor plunk with a working version: [link](https://embed.plnkr.co/PJFTFLKaTfeH4tvSEPNr/)

Comment: Thank you Stefan! That did the trick! 
I will take this even further and implement an appropriate pipe to see that if it will work that way... Cheers,

Comment: Update: I've added some data to the app and listed it using a service, then added the custom pipes for the filtering functions, but the `selectmodel` is not populating that way.

Comment: @mrTodor Post your new code and I'll take a look. :-)

Comment: The link is the same as above

Comment: @mrTodor That's because you are binding string value to `makeListFilter` instead of Object (`[ngValue]="muscleCar.name"`) and second select list can't find data to show.

Comment: ooh, so you mean that I will have to convert the string into an object and pass that object to the second select list?

Comment: @mrTodor You don't need to convert anything, you already have Object, but you are using its attribute `name` which is string: `muscleCar.name`. You have to bind `muscleCar` instead of `muscleCar.name` in your first select so second select would have data source.

Comment: Correct! thank you again. FYI: That way it will pass the data to the second select element, but the filtering function stops working, but that's another topic. Cheers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123818/discussion-between-mrtodor-and-stefan-svrkota).