# Is it possible to pass a variable in ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, loops, object

I'm new to angular and was wondering is it possible to replace firstP inside ng-repeat Directive with a variable? I'm using AngularJS v1.6.6

```
ng-repeat="option in people['firstP']"
```

```js
var people = {
    "firstP": [
        "",
        "James",
        "Jack",
    ], 
    "SecondP": [
        "",
        "Bill",
        "Bob",
    ]
};
```

Comment: Did you try it? Like `option in people[someVariable]` ?

Comment: Yes I tried that. No Luck.

Comment: use key-value pair for ng-repeat. It helps you in all ways.

Comment: Can you plz tell me, what are u trying to do.. describe fully in question. then it will be easy to solve

Comment: @user3046739 Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: @DJDaveMark  AngularJS v1.6.6

Comment: @user3046739 I edited your answer to add that, and reformatted your code a little bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is it possible to replace firstP inside ng-repeat Directive with a variable?

Yes it's possible to replace `firstP`  with a variable, after all you are just using the normal javascript **object bracket notation** in Angular.

**Solution:**

If you are trying to display the `people` object contents dynamically, then you can do it like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in people">
  <select>
    <option ng-repeat="option in people[key]">{{option}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

First you need to loop over the `people` object `keys`, then for each `key` take the relevant `array`, then loop over each `array` to display its contents.

**Note:**

Note that we can replace the `people[key]` with `value` directly in the `ng-repeat` so it becomes `ng-repeat="option in value"`.

I just used `people[key]` for the question purpose, to answer your specific question.

**Demo:**

Here's a live working [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/B5QljHPX3QJXPAvJsYpF?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to assign people object to $scope variable in order to  access people object in your html.

**HTML**

```
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="name in people[element]">{{name}}</li>
    </ul>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

var testCtrl = function($scope){
    $scope.element = 'firstP';
    $scope.people = {
       "firstP" : [
          "Jake",
          "James",
          "Jack",

      ], 
      "SecondP" : [
          "",
          "Bill",
          "Bob",

      ]};
}

app.controller('testCtrl',['$scope',testCtrl]);
```

to check https://jsfiddle.net/0zk4mfak/6/

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding,
Define the array in your controller with the $scope variable:
In controller:

```
app.controller('nameCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.people = { firstP: ['james', 'jack'] };
});
```

In Html:

```
<div ng-controller="nameCtrl">
    <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="option in people.firstP">{{option}}</li>
        </ul>

</div>
```

Try this.Hope it helps..!

Comment: `people.firstP` is exactly the same as `people["firstP"]`, that doesn't solve OP's problem

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks suspiciously like it will populate a select (dropdown) box. If that is the case use [ng-options for Angular 1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions):

> Given this array of items on the $scope:
>
> ```
> $scope.items = [{
>   id: 1,
>   label: 'aLabel',
>   subItem: { name: 'aSubItem' }
> }, {
>   id: 2,
>   label: 'bLabel',
>   subItem: { name: 'bSubItem' }
> }];
> ```
>
> This will work:
>
> ```
> <select ng-options="item as item.label for item in items track by item.id"
>         ng-model="selected"></select>
>
> $scope.selected = $scope.items[0];
> ```

or [ngFor in Angular 2](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngFor) like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39601471/344029):

> ```
> <select name="selectmake" [(ngModel)]="makeListFilter">
>     <option *ngFor="let muscleCar of muscleCars" [ngValue]="muscleCar">
>         {{muscleCar.name}}
>     </option>
> </select>
> ```